# Fast and simple way of encrypting data for sql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am really new at php so thanks for any simple answers.
I am working on a budget app that syncs the info with my sql database. What is the fastest or easiest way of encrypting data (non sensitive just for costumer ease), storing on my sql and decrypting it for use?

Comment: You can create a hash code for each user and use base64 to encode the string and concatenate with the hash.

Comment: @FelipeUmpierre: That is not encryption and what would the hash code be for? That does not make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure "budget app" and "non-sensitive" belong in the same question.

Comment: Your right it is sensitive enough that I wanted to encrypt it. Thanks for the reminder. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from PHP's built-in `mcrypt_encrypt()` and `mcrypt_decrypt()` functions.

These functions encrypt and decrypt your data based on a `KEY`. For example:

**To Encrypt:**

```
$key='mykey';
$encryptedData = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, 'Your data', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

**To Decrypt:**

```
$realData=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encryptedData, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

**[PHP's Official Document mcrypt_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)**

> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5)
>   mcrypt_encrypt — Encrypts plaintext with given parameters

**[PHP's Official Document mcrypt_decrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)**

> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5)
>   mcrypt_decrypt — Decrypts crypttext with given parameters

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm gonna try this.